# How to send attachments to a Django webapp using Rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, web-applications, chat

I have been given this chat app made in Django and asked to add a feature that helps send attachments in the chat like documents and images. I am really new to this and have no idea what to do. I did found the source from where this chat app has been developed:
[Simple Chat App using Django Rest Framework](https://code-projects.org/simple-chat-app-using-django-rest-framework/)

Following are the send and receive functions:

```js
function send(sender, receiver, message) {
    $.post('/api/messages', '{"sender": "' + sender + '", "receiver": "' + receiver + '","message": "' + message + '" }', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var box = text_box.replace('{sender}', "You");
        box = box.replace('{message}', message);
        $('#board').append(box);
        scrolltoend();
    })
}


function receive() {
    $.get('/api/messages/' + sender_id + '/' + receiver_id, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length !== 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]);
                var box = text_box.replace('{sender}', data[i].sender);
                box = box.replace('{message}', data[i].message);
                box = box.replace('right', 'left blue lighten-5');
                $('#board').append(box);

                scrolltoend();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is the code in the html file:

```html
<script>
  // For receiving, set global variables to be used by the 'receive' function
  sender_id = "{{ receiver.id }}"; //Context variable for receiver
  receiver_id = "{{ request.user.id }}"; //Context variable for current logged in user
  //For sending
  $(function () {
    scrolltoend(); // Function to show the latest message, which is at the bottom of the message box, by scrolling to the end
    //Handling the submit event to send the message.
    $('#chat-box').on('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var message = $('#id_message');
      send('{{ request.user.username }}', '{{ receiver.username }}', message.val()); //Send function will be defined within 'chat.js'
      message.val(''); //Clear content of the the input field after sending
    })
    setInterval(() => {
      getUsers({{ request.user.id }}, doc => {
        let list = ''
        doc.map(userItem => {
          list += userItem
        })
        $('#users').html(list)
      });
  }, 1000)
        })
</script>
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: Which front-end-framework are you using?

Comment: HTML and CSS
the chat box is working like a form and JS functions are being used to send and recieve msgs. i will add the send and receive functions